# JS testing: Is there any npm library containing only assertions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, assert

I've wrote very-very simple testing engine for my application, that totally satisfies me.

However, currently test passing logic is as simple as:

```
return foo === bar
```

or

```
return foo.length === 3
```

Therefore, if test fails, I have to manually console.log() those variables, in order to analyze their values. I do not want to install full testing library like Mocha, instead I would like to only install assertions library, so I could use `assertEquals()`, `assertTrue()` etc.

I've found https://github.com/philbooth/check-types.js/ but it does not support ES6 modules, which is also requirement in my case.

Comment: Did you check [Chai](http://www.chaijs.com/) ?

Comment: I'm checking it right now, not sure, but seems it is exactly what I need :) I thought it is another big testing framework like Mocha

Comment: No, it's only for assertions. It's comfortable to use because you can select the most suitable syntax for your needs.

Comment: Cool, exactly what I need! Thank you, Anna :)

Comment: You're welcome ;)